# Java no class def found error elasticsearch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-7, mingw, elasticsearch

I followed these steps on https://github.com/karmi/tire to install elasticsearch for use with ruby on rails

```
curl -k -L -o elasticsearch-0.17.6.tar.gz http://github.com/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-0.17.6.tar.gz 

tar -zxvf elasticsearch-0.17.6.tar.gz

./elasticsearch-0.17.6/bin/elasticsearch -f
```

I am running this on MinGW on windows 7, and most of the process went
smoothly.

However, as I try to start the server with ./elasticsearch-0.17.6/bin/
elasticsearch -f I get a java no class def found error:

```
$ ./elasticsearch-0.17.6/bin/elasticsearch
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/
elasticsearch/bootstrap/ElasticSearch
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.ElasticSearch
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class:
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.ElasticSearch.  Program will exit.
```

What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mingw translates paths and environment variables into UNIX equivalents. It's designed to work with its own tools, and running something foreign to it, like `java.exe`, doesn't always work out as you'd expect. In particular, that script builds a Java classpath in the variable `ES_CLASSPATH` and then passes it to Java using the `-cp` switch, and I bet it's passing Java a path it simply doesn't understand.

What I would do is find the line that executes `java.exe` in that script, and make a copy of the line prepended with "echo" so that you can see the command line that's being executed. Then adjust the script to provide a proper Java classpath.

Comment: Oh i didn't realize it was a script. I thought it was a binary. This makes debugging it much easier. Thanks!